What did armor look like in the Vedic period?
What does armor and helmets look like in the Vedic period regarding the structure and visuals. Are there any artifacts which depict the armor? What was its material?

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s). Recommend you start with Wikipedia and follow the links

Took me a few minutes to think of looking here, but it seems like this wikipedia link might answer most of this question? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_armour#Vedic_period Pretty much everything but perhaps how it looked

@T.E.D. a more visual representation though.

@Haridasa: There don't appear to be any surviving armour pieces from the area and period, and the literature doesn't describe the armour in technical detail.

The best that can be done is artist's impressions, since there doesn't seem to be any surviving Vedic period armour. However, the warfare of the Vedic Aryans seems to have been quite similar to that of other peoples of the Middle Bronze Age, with chariot-mounted archers as the most important units. They looked about like this (image from Warfare History Network):

These were expensive units to raise and equip, requiring two men, their armour, two horses and a chariot to put a single archer onto the battlefield. However, they were effective: they used expensive composite bows, giving them more range and hitting power than the simpler bows used by infantry, and their mobility allowed them to attack a single enemy unit and withdraw before infantry could move to concentrate against them. Naturally, chariot warriors were nobility.
Lightweight chariots with spoked wheels appear to have been invented by the early Indo-Europeans. Earlier cultures had "war-waggons" with heavier construction and solid wheels, which moved fairly slowly. The key feature of chariots was that they could move much faster than infantry, allowing them to attack or withdraw at their choice, and to avoid hand-to-hand combat with infantry.
Chariots became obsolete when selective breeding of horses reached the point when they could carry an armoured man. At that point, cavalry became more cost-effective than chariots, although it took centuries for cavalry to spread to the outskirts of Europe.
Addendum: the armour is "scale", many small pieces of bronze sewn to a strong cloth undergarment, with substantial overlaps between the scales. This matches the Vedic lines about "sewn armour", and the appearance of armour on statuary. This does not require advanced metalworking, although it is quite heavy and gets damaged easily. However, it is also easy to repair.

Citations would improve this answer.

@SPavel: Yes - omitted by mistake. Now fixed.

The assertion that chariots became obsolete when breeding produced a horse that could carry a man is not supported by the source, and would be a great surprise to my Celtic ancestors who used chariots long after that date.

Image cited, last paragraph revised.

@JohnDallman That's interesting, so Kushanas a prevalent ethnic group within India seemed to have a similar type of armor.

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EndYkmCXMAM38Uz.jpg
https://wildfiregames.com/forum/uploads/imageproxy/zFolrMX.jpg.b1b84df7c5d4d70f26067894740c0458.jpg
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6c/Kumara%2C_The_Divine_General_LACMA_M.85.279.3.jpg/170px-Kumara%2C_The_Divine_General_LACMA_M.85.279.3.jpg

@Haridasa: Added a bit about the construction.

@JohnDallman ty

@njuffa - the spoked wheel chariot is attributed to the Indo-Europeans. The Mesopotamian version might better be called a "war-wagon." The solid wheels and wagon shape made it heavier and slower, and it was pulled by Kunga, which was a (now extinct) donkey-onager hybrid. The horse wasn't introduced to Mesopotamia until ~2200BC, over a thousand years after its initial domestication by the Proto-Indo-Europeans, and they probably arrived with the spoked wheel chariot.

Added war-waggons and their differences from chariots.
